# PermissionError Python - os.rename

Tags: python, regex, permissions

I am just trying to get a number from a file and rename it to another directory. Can you help me?

My code below:

```
path_txt = 'temp'

name_files1 = os.listdir(path_txt) 
for TXT in name_files1:
    with open(os.path.join(path_txt,TXT), "r") as content:  
        search = re.search(r'(\d{21,30})|'
                                  r'(\d{7})\-\s*(\d{2})\.(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})|'
                                  r'(\d{7})\.?(\d{2})\/?(\d{4})\.?(\d)\.?(\d{2})\.?(\d{4})|'
                                  r'(\d{7})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})|'
                                  r'(\d{7})\-(\d{2})\.(\d{4})\.(\d)\.(\d{2})\-(\d{4})', content.read())  


    text = content.read()
    if search is not None:  
        name1 = search.group(0)  
        name1 = re.sub(r"\D", "", name1)  
        fp = os.path.join("20_digitos", name1 + "_%d.txt")  
        postfix = 0
        while os.path.exists(fp % postfix): # Verifica se o arquivo já existe na pasta, se existir incrementa +1 em %d de fp
            postfix += 1
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
            fp % postfix
        )
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "---", line 30, in <module>
fp % postfix
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'temp\\Processo ID 1000000.pdf .txt' -> '20_digitos\\00025087420135020003_0.txt'
```

Comment: ...have you checked if the file is open in another process?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? You shouldn't be able to do `text = content.read()` outside the `with` block because the `content` file should be closed. And if it's open, you shouldn't be trying to rename it.

Comment: @Farhan.K Yes  

@PM2Ring I was not using `text` (i forgot to comment it) but the problem, in fact, was the identation, thanks a lot.